# maven clean not working in sts with tomcat 1.8

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am upgrading my project from
1)  Tomcat 1.7 to tomcat 1.8
2) STS 2.* to STS3.*
3) maven 2.* to Maven 3.*

after upgrading in STS when I do maven clean I am getting below error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Bna4AllService 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/tomcat-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.776 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-14T17:46:34+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\nreddy\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
```

My POM.xml file below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.eeft</groupId>
    <artifactId>bna4AllService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Bna4AllService</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.eeft</groupId>
            <artifactId>bna4AllServiceImplementation</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                   <configuration>
                      <archive>
                         <manifest>
                         </manifest>
                         <manifestEntries>
                            <DisableIBMJAXWSEngine>true</DisableIBMJAXWSEngine>
                         </manifestEntries>
                      </archive>
                   </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin> 
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> 
                   <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                   <configuration> 
                      <server>myserver</server>
                      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url> 
                   </configuration> 
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.13</version>
                  </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am very new to the mvaen build please help me resolving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configuration of tomcat is wrong.
In your pom.xml, add the tomcat plugin. (You can use this for both Tomcat 7 and 8):

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- Tomcat plugin -->  
<plugin>  
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
 <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
 <version>2.2</version>  
 <configuration>  
  <url>http:// localhost:8080/manager/text</url>  
  <server>TomcatServer</server>    *(From maven > settings.xml)*
  <username>*yourtomcatusername*</username>  
  <password>*yourtomcatpassword*</password>   
 </configuration>   
</plugin>
```

**tomcat-users.xml**

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>  
        <role rolename="manager-script"/>   
        <user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />  
</tomcat-users>
```

**settings.xml** (maven > conf)

```
<servers>  
    <server>
       <id>TomcatServer</id>
       <username>admin</username>
       <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

*** deploy/re-deploy**

mvn tomcat7:deploy OR mvn tomcat7:redeploy

Tried this on (Both Ubuntu and Windows 8/10):
 * Jdk 7 & Tomcat 7
 * Jdk 8 & Tomcat 7
 * Jdk 8 & Tomcat 8

haven't tried it on Jdk 7 & Tomcat 8 though :)

Note:
Tomcat manager should be running or properly setup, before you can use it with maven.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thenk you! Hohenheim.. Let me try this.

Comment: This tutorial is not bad at all [link](http://blog.devcanvas.org/deploy-a-web-application-from-the-command-line-by-using-tomcat-maven-plugin/)