# Maven web project is not properly deployed on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment

I have a maven web project which is working fine when I run MAVEN BUILD and take the war file and manually deploy it in the standalone server.

When I use 'run on server' option in eclipse, the project is seems deployed in Tomcat server but the class files are missing in the workspace server location. 
only pom.xml and pom.properties are only available.

Not sure why the war file is not properly deployed when I run it through 'run on server' option.

(I tried with mvn eclipse:eclipse command to convert the Maven into Java web project but unsuccessful on deployment)

I have M2E plugin in my eclipse. My tomcat version is Tomcat 8.

EDITED: my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>reports</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Report Service</name>

       <parent>
        <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>a1-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <rest-assured.version>2.4.0</rest-assured.version>
        <rootPath>${basedir}</rootPath>
        <main.basedir>${project.basedir}</main.basedir>
        <commons-pool2.version>2.4.1</commons-pool2.version>

        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z</maven.build.timestamp.format>

        <springframework-version>1.3.1.RELEASE</springframework-version>
        <swagger.version>2.1.4</swagger.version>
        <springfox.version>2.3.1</springfox.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.2.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <asciidoctor.version>1.5.3</asciidoctor.version>
        <asciidoctorj.pdf.version>1.5.0-alpha.11</asciidoctorj.pdf.version>

        <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>        

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- start swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-staticdocs</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.robwin</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger2markup</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version> ${springframework-version}</version>            
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
              <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
              <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version> ${springframework-version}</version>            
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- end swagger -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
              <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
              <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>

        <finalName>reports.${buildNumber}</finalName>

        <plugins>

        <!-- start swagger -->
        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>1.5.2.1</version>
             <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                      <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
                      <version>1.5.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                      <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
                      <version>1.5.0-alpha.11</version>
                  </dependency>
                <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
                      <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
                      <version>9.0.4.0</version>
                  </dependency>
             </dependencies>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                      <id>generate-docs</id>
                      <phase>package</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <backend>html</backend>
                          <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/docs/asciidoc</sourceDirectory>
                          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-docs/html</outputDirectory>
                          <attributes>
                              <toclevels>2</toclevels>
                              <toc>left</toc>
                              <doctype>book</doctype>
                              <generated>src/docs/asciidoc/generated</generated>
                          </attributes>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
                <execution>
                      <id>generate-pdf-doc</id>
                      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <backend>pdf</backend>
                          <sourceHighlighter>rouge</sourceHighlighter>
                          <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/docs/asciidoc</sourceDirectory>
                          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-docs/pdf</outputDirectory>
                          <attributes>
                              <icons>font</icons>
                              <pagenums />
                              <toc />
                              <idprefix />
                              <idseparator>-</idseparator>
                              <generated>src/docs/asciidoc/generated</generated>
                          </attributes>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>       
        <!-- end swagger -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
                    <format>${project.version}.r{0,number}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>buildNumber0</item>
                    </items>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                            <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                            <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-installed</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>${project.artifactId}.${project.packaging}</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- start swagger -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.asciidoctor
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            asciidoctor-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.5.2.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>
                                                process-asciidoc
                                            </goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-compiler-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [3.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- end swagger -->

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Show us your pom.xml

Comment: Hi Hohenheim, can you find anything wrong with my pom.xml

Comment: Try to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623009/maven-clean-not-working-in-sts-with-tomcat-1-8/36624620?noredirect=1#comment60845453_36624620) i answered for the same problem i think

Comment: Is there any specific maven command to start Tomcat 8 version? I can see tomcat7:run to start tomcat7 server.

Comment: it's the same , it works for tomcat8